# Entity Framework: the operation failed: the relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm getting the following exception when trying to save a complex entity graph:

> Entity Framework: The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.

As the graph is quite complex I can't find out which relationship is causing the problem.

Is it possible to query the `ChangeTracker` to check which relationship is failing?

Comment: Please provide the code that is giving this error